# Where can I ask for an accessibility review for a site?

Tags: review, accessibility

I'm not *too,* too far (I hope) from finishing a site. I want to have it reviewed with an eye to its accessibility.

The site's job is to display streaming, up-to-the-10-second-period stock-option data.

Does anyone know of a group or forum where I can post a request for a review of the site's accessibility?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about its usability by people with handicaps? Or whether it's accessible from different places on the planet?

Comment: @Peter Rowell -- the former, so that I can improve it if necessary; I can't do too much about the latter.

Comment: Related (hopefully helps you out): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118038/web-site-compliance-with-the-americans-with-disabilities-act-ada

Comment: quick test for accessiblity are : black and white version, light and moderate red, blue, green, orange, yellow hues (this will allow you to discernate if the content can easily be seen by color blind people) then you can deactivate css and javascript, if you still get your reading levels and most of the content you are about 80% accessibility bullet proof

Comment: Real quick test for accessibility:  look at it in lynx or some similar browser.  That's what a blind person with a screen reader is likely to experience.

Comment: The lynx advice is completely wrong. I use Jaws as a screen reader and it does it's own special formatting of the HTML content to make it easier for a blind person to understand. Also some text only browsers do not support javascript well if at all while any browser a blind person is using does.

Comment: I'd be willing to review the site since I'm a screen reader user, you'll need to post some way for me to get in contact with you in a comment though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where are you located? Is there either a local or national vision impairment group/community you could reach out to? Here in Canada we have the CNIB.

If I were in your shoes, I'd reach out to them and ask if they could lend a hand.

If you can't get in contact with such a group, try holding some usability tests for people with vision impairments.

I'd also try speaking to a local university and see if they have a department or office that works with students with disabilities. Someone at the department might be able to help you and point out things that you should watch out for or things you have missed.

Comment: This is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for professional help, you should look for people who do usability studies -- they tend to cover the accessibility angle as well.

For internet help, I'd suggest [SitePoint's forums](http://sitepoint.com/forums) -- they have a [website review forum](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/website-reviews-12/) that has a lot of quite accessibility-focused people hanging around.

In the interest of full disclosure, I was a moderator there for a few years in recent memory and still hang around in that community.